# List of the (row, col) of the n largest values in a numeric pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, indexing, argmax

Given a Pandas `DataFrame` of numeric values how can one produce a list of the `.loc` cell locations that one can then use to then obtain the corresponding `n` largest values in the entire DataFame?

For example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1.3 | 3.6 | 33 | 61.38 | 0.3 |
| Y | 3.14 | 2.71 | 64 | 23.2 | 21 |
| Z | 1024 | 42 | 66 | 137 | 22.2 |
| T | 63.123 | 111 | 1.23 | 14.16 | 50.49 |

An `n` of 3 would produce the (row,col) pairs for the values `1024`, `137` and `111`.

These locations could then, as usual, be fed to `.loc` to extract those values from the DataFrame. i.e.

```
df.loc['Z','A']
df.loc['Z','D']
df.loc['T','B']
```

Note: It is easy to mistake this question for one that involves `.idxmax`.  That isn't applicable due to the fact that there may be multiple values selected from a row and/or column in the n largest.

Comment: Please post your expected output. The requirement is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```py
>>> data = {0 : [1.3, 3.14, 1024, 63.123], 1: [3.6, 2.71, 42, 111], 2 : [33, 64, 66, 1.23], 3 : [61.38, 23.2, 137, 14.16], 4 : [0.3, 21, 22.2, 50.49] }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
          0       1      2       3      4
0     1.300    3.60  33.00   61.38   0.30
1     3.140    2.71  64.00   23.20  21.00
2  1024.000   42.00  66.00  137.00  22.20
3    63.123  111.00   1.23   14.16  50.49
>>>
>>> a = list(zip(*df.stack().nlargest(3).index.labels))
>>> a
[(2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
>>> # then ...
>>> df.loc[a[0]]
1024.0
>>> 
>>> # all sorted in decreasing order ...
>>> list(zip(*df.stack().nlargest(20).index.labels))
[(2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 0), (0, 3), (3, 4), (2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 4), (3, 3), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (3, 2), (0, 4)]
```

**Edit:** In pandas versions 0.24.0 and above, `MultiIndex.labels` has been replaced by `MultiIndex.codes`(see Deprecations in [What’s new in 0.24.0 (January 25, 2019)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html)). The above code will throw `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'` and needs to be updated as follows:

```py
>>> a = list(zip(*df.stack().nlargest(3).index.codes))
>>> a
[(2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
```

**Edit 2:** This question has become a "moving target", as the OP keeps changing it (this is my last update/edit). In the last update, OP's dataframe looks as follows:

```py
>>> data = {'A' : [1.3, 3.14, 1024, 63.123], 'B' : [3.6, 2.71, 42, 111], 'C' : [33, 64, 66, 1.23], 'D' : [61.38, 23.2, 137, 14.16], 'E' : [0.3, 21, 22.2, 50.49] }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'T'])
>>> df
          A       B      C       D      E
X     1.300    3.60  33.00   61.38   0.30
Y     3.140    2.71  64.00   23.20  21.00
Z  1024.000   42.00  66.00  137.00  22.20
T    63.123  111.00   1.23   14.16  50.49
```

The desired output can be obtained using:

```py
>>> a = df.stack().nlargest(3).index 
>>> a
MultiIndex([('Z', 'A'),
            ('Z', 'D'),
            ('T', 'B')],
           )
>>>
>>> df.loc[a[0]]
1024.0
```

Comment: I removed my apparently erroneous comment about `.nlargest`.

Comment: The `a = ...` produces `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'` on my system.

Comment: Do you have `MultiIndex.codes` instead of `MultiIndex.labels`? -- see Deprecations in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html

Comment: Ah, yes. I've updated the question to use the word `codes` indicating the deprecation of `labels`.

Comment: I edited the answer to cover both `labels` (old) and `codes` (new). Does it work for you now?

Comment: Almost.  See my revision.  What I'm after apparently aren't the "codes" but whatever is used to describe the things that do a lookup on the `.index` and `.columns` indexes.  Is that "names"?

Comment: Your last revision has made the question (and the answer) different from your original one. This renders the answers that people provided you with useless. Your problem  may be solved, but the page will be of limited use (and confusing) for others, who may even decide to downvote. Also, if the answers were helpful, please consider upvoting, if they solved your problem, please consider accepting in addition to upvoting.

Comment: I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  Thanks for your patience in adding to the solution to address my shifting question. In my own defense, both the behavior and the terminology regarding `.loc` is shifting as well and I'm sure others experience this same confusion, so it is important to contrast the two questions and their respective solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `np.unravel_index` on the `np.argsort`

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 5
df = pd.DataFrame([[11, 3, 50, -3],
                   [5, 73, 11, 100],
                   [75, 9, -2, 44]])


s_ix = np.argsort(df.values, axis=None)[::-1][:N]
labels = np.unravel_index(s_ix, df.shape)
labels = list(zip(*labels))

print(labels) # --> [(1, 3), (2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3)]
print(df.loc[labels[0]])  # --> 100
```